# Switch between datasets in a d3 barchart

Tags: d3.js

I need to switch between two datasets from the same csv file, 
I have a small dataset of predicted v actual league positions from last years English premier League.

- dataset1  = Actual League Position
- dataset2 = Predicted league Position

My render data function does not seem to be working as my second dataset (i.e. Predicted) is not displayed when i click the radio button - see attached pic - only the actual position dataset is being displayed
I've provided a link to my code: [github link to my code](https://bl.ocks.org/fergusie/ee6a74122468673e8c5e8b047c96c0fb/28b28b97b1f7a3879c50b0226e05af7a0dfc5526)

Copy of relevant code below

```
function render(data){

var  bars = g.selectAll("bar")
.data(data)

//enter
bars.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Team); })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x2(d.Predicted_Finish); })
      .style("fill", "#a02f2b")

//exit
bars.exit()
.transition()
.duration(300)
.remove()

}


function init()
{

//setup the svg
 var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 65, left: 110}//position of axes 
frame
width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;


//setup our ui
d3.select("#Actual")
    .on("click", function(d,i) {
        console.log(Actual);
        render(Actual)
    })   
d3.select("#Predicted")
    .on("click", function(d,i) {
        console.log(Predicted);
        render(Predicted)
    })   

render(Actual)
}

init();
```

Answer (score 1):

This code can be significantly simplified.

First, couple of format problems:

1. Improperly placed `<body>`, and no `</body>` or `</html>`
2. `<form>` around your buttons is not needed (it's causing a submit)

Second, your code can be restructured.  You don't need a full enter, update, exit pattern here since your data doesn't really change.  You just want to toggle between two variables in your single dataset.  With that in mind, here's how it ends up looking:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CSS Example</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Passion+One" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    .my-text {
      font-size: 1.95em;
      font-family: 'Passion One', cursive;
      fill: #000000;
    }

    .bar {
      fill: #71df3e;
    }

    .bar:hover {
      fill: white;
    }

    .axis--x path {
      display: none;
    }

    body {
      background-color: orange;
    }

    .axisx text {
      fill: black;
    }

    .axisy text {
      fill: black;
    }

    .axisx line {
      stroke: black;
    }

    .axisy line {
      stroke: black;
    }

    .axisx path {
      stroke: black;
    }

    .axisy path {
      stroke: black;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="buttons">
    <button id="Actual">Actual</button>
    <button id="Predicted">Predicted</button>
  </div>

  <svg width="1200" height="500">

    <text class="my-text" x="330" y="20">EPL PREDICTIONS VERSUS REALITY</text>

  </svg>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //define svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 65,
        left: 110
      } //position of axes frame
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    //next our graph
    var g = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) {
        d.Actual_Finish = +d.Actual_Finish;
        d.Predicted_Finish = +d.Predicted_Finish;
        return d;
      }, function(error, data)
      {

        if (error) throw error;

        data = data;

        //define our x and y axis scales and variables, remembering we have 2 x                     variables 
        x1 = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([800, 1])
          //experiment with the max numbers to bring the x scale within the margin
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
            return d.Actual_Finish;
          })]);
        y = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, height])
          .padding(0.5).domain(data.map(function(d) {
            return d.Team;
          }));

        //append x axis to svg
        g.append("g")
          .style("font", "14px arial") //font and size of x axis labels
          .attr("class", "axisx")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x1).ticks(20))
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(d3.axisBottom(x1))
          .append("text")
          .attr("x", 450) //position of x1 axis label: x co-ordinate
          .attr("y", 35) //position of x axis label: y co-ordinate
          .attr("dx", "1.0em") //also position of X axis label
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text("League Position");

        //append y axis to svg
        g.append("g") //append y axis to svg
          .style("font", "14px arial") //font and size of y axis labels
          .attr("class", "axisy")
          .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(20)) //no. of ticks on y axis
          .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-360)") //rotate the axis label text by -90
          .attr("y", -20) //position of y axis label
          .attr("dy", "1.0em") //sets the unit amount the y axis label moves above
          .attr("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Team");

        var bars = g.selectAll('.bar')
          .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x1", 0)
          .attr("x2", 0)
          .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
          .style("fill", "#a02f2b");

        render('Actual_Finish')

        function render(which) {
          bars.attr("y", function(d) {
              return y(d.Team);
            })
            .attr("width", function(d) {
              return x1(d[which]);
            });
        }

        d3.select("#Actual")
          .on("click", function(d, i) {
            render('Actual_Finish')
          });
        d3.select("#Predicted")
          .on("click", function(d, i) {
            render('Predicted_Finish')
          });

      });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Running code can be seen [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ccbs2wX0OJjH2WNSQvZS?p=preview).